# how to display array of message in magento bundle model

Tags: arrays, magento, message

I'm working on the bundle model to check on the quantity of each bundle .. I want to display the error message in array so I can return all the errors at one time. how can I pass array to this line
Mage::helper('bundle')->**('msg')? I want to add my errors array instead of message to be like this 
Mage::helper('bundle')->**($errors). but when I do so it returns array.

if there is also any other solution I'd be grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display in forntend site, look like this.

```
$message = new array();
foreach( $array in $element ) 
{
    ...
    $message[] = Mage::helper('bundle')->__('msg');
    ...
}
Mage::throwException(implode(', ', $message));
```